# UPDATE FROM another table value with CASE SUBSTRING and WHERE

Tags: mysql

I tried to update my main table --> **budget** with values from **item_master** table with condition
Here's the table structure

budget :

```
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| department        | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| section           | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| budget_id         | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| carmaker          | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| carline           | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| phase             | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| purpose           | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| order_plan        | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| required_date     | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| subgroup          | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| item_desc         | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| item_code         | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| qty               | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| curr              | char(3)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| price             | decimal(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| amount_ori        | decimal(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| amount            | decimal(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| amount_reduce_ori | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| amount_reduce_usd | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| qty_reduce        | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| qty_final         | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| amount_final      | decimal(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| status            | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | uncommited |                |
| source            | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| coa_production    | char(7)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| coa_general       | char(7)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| hfm_cr            | char(6)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| hfm_pl            | char(6)       | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| update_record     | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| user              | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

item_master :

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subgroup       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_desc      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_code      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uom            | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price          | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coa_production | char(7)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| coa_general    | char(7)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hfm_cr         | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hfm_pl         | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to get **coa_production** or **coa general** , depend on **purpose** field
if the first three (3) characters = 'PRO' then use **coa_production**, else **use coa_general** with item_code as the unique string/foreign keys

Here's my current code :

```
UPDATE budget CASE
WHEN SUBSTR(purpose,1,3) = 'PRO' THEN
SET coa_production = (SELECT coa_production FROM item_master WHERE budget.item_code = item_master.item_code) ELSE
SET coa_general = (SELECT coa_general FROM item_master WHERE budget.item_code = item_master.item_code) END
```

my goal is when purpose = 'PRO' then the only field that has to be filled is coa_production using the value from item_master table, so does if purpose = 'GEN' then the only field that has to be filled is coa_general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would express this using an update join:

```
UPDATE budget b
LEFT JOIN item_master im
    ON b.item_code = im.item_code
SET
    b.coa_production = CASE WHEN LEFT(b.purpose, 3) = 'PRO' THEN im.coa_production END,
    b.coa_general = CASE WHEN LEFT(b.purpose, 3) = 'GEN' THEN im.coa_general END
WHERE
    LEFT(b.purpose, 3) IN ('PRO', 'GEN');
```

Note that a left join (rather than an inner join) is required here, to keep the behavior the same as your original query.  Using a left join, a `NULL` would be assigned to a column which did not find any matching record in the `item_master` table.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried your code then the result was either coa_production and coa_general in budget table have filled both, my goal is when purpose = 'PRO' then the only field that has to be filled is coa_production using the value from item_master table, sorry for not mentioning this on the original question

Comment: @owf Please check the updated answer, I misread your requirements.

Comment: i tried your updated code, but got an error on the last statement --> IN('PRO','GEN'); instead

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ('PRO', 'GEN')' at line 8

Comment: Sorry, should be: `WHERE LEFT(b.purpose, 3) IN ('PRO', 'GEN')`